# How to create a listing of unique names from a list

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a list of names in column A and numbers (1-4) in Column B.

I need a formula to extract the names to Columns D, E, F, etc., where if multiple names have the same number (1-4) each name would appear in its own column.

```
Have This                       Need this result

Column
A    B                          C   D     E      F
greg 1                          3  Tim
hank 2                          2  Hank  Mike
mike 2                          1  Greg
tim 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If C1 has '3', then the following will give you all names that have 3 in column B

```
=transpose(filter(A:A,B:B=c1))
```